# Rotating around computed point using PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to rotate a drawing around a specific point using PGF commands. As long as I hard code the center of rotation, this works just fine:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (3, 3);
  % Rotate around (1, 1).
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointxy{1}{1}}
  \pgftransformrotate{20}
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointxy{-1}{-1}}
  \draw (0.5, 0.5) -- (1.5, 1.5);
  \draw (1.5, 0.5) -- (0.5, 1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I don't want to rotate around a hard coded center but around a computed one. I compute my center using `\coordinate (x) at ($<some computation$);`. I tried the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (3, 3);
  \coordinate (x) at (1, 1); % In real life: ($<computation>$)
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointscale{1}{\pgfpointanchor{x}{center}}}
  \pgftransformrotate{20}
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpointanchor{x}{center}}}
  \draw (0.5, 0.5) -- (1.5, 1.5);
  \draw (1.5, 0.5) -- (0.5, 1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now what seems to happen is that the coordinate specified in the second shift is affected by the preceding `\pgftransformrotate`, even though I defined it before the transformations. Thus, the drawing is offset in the second example.

Can I somehow prevent my computed center of rotation from being transformed by the `pgftransform` commands? Or is there any other solution to my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are surely other solutions but the first one can be :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\newdimen\myx
\newdimen\myy 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (3, 3);
  \coordinate (x) at (1, 1); % In real life: ($<computation>$) 
  \pgfextractx{\myx}{\pgfpointanchor{x}{center}} 
  \pgfextracty{\myy}{\pgfpointanchor{x}{center}} 
  \draw[red] (0.5, 0.5) -- (1.5, 1.5) (1.5, 0.5) -- (0.5, 1.5); 
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{\myx}{\myy}}  
  \pgftransformrotate{20}
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{-\myx}{-\myy}}    
     \draw[blue] (0.5, 0.5) -- (1.5, 1.5) (1.5, 0.5) -- (0.5, 1.5);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great hint, thank you! I wrapped your solution into macros (see [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49123/12861)) and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

First a simple TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (3, 3);
  \coordinate (x) at (2, 2); % In real life: ($<computation>$)
\begin{scope}[rotate around={45:(x)}]
  \draw (0.5, 0.5) -- (1.5, 1.5);
  \draw (1.5, 0.5) -- (0.5, 1.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Second, the PGF version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (3, 3);
\coordinate (x) at (2, 2); % In real life: ($<computation>$)
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5mm] (O) at (x) {};
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{x}{center}}
\pgfgetlastxy{\myx}{\myy}
\pgftransformrotate{20}
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-\myx}{-\myy}}%This has no effect if x used, x is the origin now
\draw (0.5, 0.5) -- (1.5, 1.5);
\draw (1.5, 0.5) -- (0.5, 1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using Altermundus' solution but to reduce clutter, I introduced two macros:

```
\def\savePoint#1#2{%
  \expandafter\newdimen\csname #2x\endcsname\expandafter\pgfextractx\csname #2x\endcsname{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
  \expandafter\newdimen\csname #2y\endcsname\expandafter\pgfextracty\csname #2y\endcsname{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}}
\def\getPoint#1{\pgfpoint{\csname #1x\endcsname}{\csname #1y\endcsname}}
```

Now I write a little more compact code:

```
  \coordinate (x) at (1, 1);
  \savePoint{x}{x}
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointscale{1}{\getPoint{x}}}
  \pgftransformrotate{20}
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\getPoint{x}}}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `\pgfgetlastxy` like percusse is another solution but you need to place it correctly.