# Where can I find documentation about TikZ/TikZPicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, documentation

When looking for different packages of creating timelines, I came across the following one:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[snake=zigzag, line before snake = 5mm, line after snake = 5mm]
%draw horizontal line   
\draw (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[snake] (2,0) -- (4,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[snake] (5,0) -- (7,0);

%draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,4,5,7}
   \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);

%draw nodes
\draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 0 $} node[above=3pt] {$   $};
\draw (1,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 1 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 10 $};
\draw (2,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 2 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 20 $};
\draw (3,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=3pt] {$  $};
\draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 5 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 50 $};
\draw (5,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 6 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 60 $};
\draw (6,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=3pt] {$  $};
\draw (7,0) node[below=3pt] {$ n $} node[above=3pt] {$ 10n $};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When typesetting, we get this:

[image]

But although the code says `\usepackage{tikz}`, there is not a package with this name. According to the CTAN site, there is a macro package called [pgf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) that *«comes with a user-friendly syntax layer called TikZ.»*

I have checked the [pgf documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), of course, but there doesn't seem to be a section related to the code I posted above. There are many options (some are very nice too), but nothing like what I'm searching. Am I missing something? I'd like to know what can I do beyond what that code offers (*if* there is something, of course).

Also: what is TikZPicture? Is this what I should be looking for? I'm quite confused at the moment.

Comment: You are on the right track: TikZ is (basically) syntactic sugar on top of `pgf`. It is described in the first few chapters of the pgfmanual. In particular, the tutorials are very helpful to get you started.

Comment: A simple Google search for "tikz" shows you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ and http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf, both explain that TikZ is part of PGF. See the [`pgfmanual`](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) for the documentation.

Comment: I saw that it's part of PGF. What I was asking, apart from confirmation of that, was what part of the manual I should check to understand better the code I posted in my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. `pgf` is a huge toolbox for graphics in TeX.
2. `tikz` is something built on top of that, with much user-friendlier syntax.  Most people use `tikz` and not `pgf`; the manual for `tikz` (and `pgf` at the same time) is called `pgfmanual`, which might be confusing.
3. `tikzpicture` is a LaTeX environment defined by `tikz`.

The code you mentioned uses `tikz`; I'd recommend you to read chapters/sections 1 (basic ideas), 2 (the first tutorial, with examples of (among others) lines and nodes), 15.10 (decorations) and 56 (`\foreach`) of `pgfmanual`.  Notice also that "snakes" were replaced by "decorations" in newer versions of `tikz`.

Comment: Oops, you have already mentioned the obsolete version info. Do you mind copying the message in my answer to yours and I delete mine? Maybe I can add the new way of drawing the image given above if you don't mind.

Comment: @percusse: Well, I'd leave it as it is.  This way anyone reading this has some info from my answer and more info on drawing particular things in yours.

Comment: Thank you! :) I already had a look. It's not going to be easy, but well... :D

Comment: @Alenanno: it's easier than you might think, unless you want to do really strange things.  Don't forget to take a look at http://texample.net/tikz/ !

Answer (score 7):

Since you have the TikZ/PGF relation in the comments and answers, here is another reason for the absence of a documentation. If you look at the definition file under PGF package you would see the following lines

```
\PackageWarning{pgf}{Snakes have been superseded by decorations. Use
the decoration libraries instead of the snakes library}

\usepgflibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.shapes}
```

So that particular usage of `snakes` is now obsolete and replaced by the libraries given above. For a particular example of the difference between TikZ and pgf, please have a look at [my previous answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49110/rotating-around-computed-point-using-pgf/49127#49127) which shows two identical ways of higher and lower levels of drawing. I hope you appreciate that TikZ is pretty much easier to use since it uses a pretty fluent english command style.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to accept the other one, but I upvoted yours because of good additional info. :)